# Is there a way to implement a method on a child class that I can access the attributes from it's child?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm trying to build an app to learn Java, basically it's a Football Match on console.

The Class Player has all the attributes like name, number, age..
There are other classes which extends from Player, they are the Player Roles (Striker, Defender, Midfielder, Goalkeeper).
The Roles implements a Interface that has the methods to get each one it's own attribute formula (Like Defense Power and Attack Power).
So then there's a method which is the General Power, this one's formula is equal to everyone, independent to the player's role.

If I set the General Power in the child's class methods, I'll have to write in each Role Class the same code, several times (I'm almost sure that it's wrong.. code reuse).

Maybe I've to implement the method on the interface, but I've no idea how to proceed.

I've got a link on [GitHub](https://github.com/JohnneSouza/footballgame) - It's on the Develop Branch.

And here below is some code to try to understand what I'm trying to figure out.

```
public interface PlayerAttributes {

    PlayerPosition getPlayerPosition(PlayerPosition position);

    Double getAttackPower(Float value);
}

class Player {

    String name;
    Integer number;
    PlayerPosition position; //Enum
}

public class Defender extends Player implements PlayerAttributes {

    @Override
    public PlayerPosition getPlayerPosition(PlayerPosition position) {
        return PlayerPosition.DEFENDER;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getAttackPower(Float value) {
        return value * 1.2;
    }

    @Override
    public Double getDefensePower(Float value) {
        return value * 2.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: @shmosel I've posted a link to my project on GitHub and provided some code to try to explain better.

Comment: You may want to look into making `Player` an `abstract` class instead.  Also, why is a value being passed in for `getAttackPower` and `getDefensePower`?

Comment: @Powerlord Do you mean in the Interface? The user will insert a value for theses, and now that you've pointed that I think I may refactor theses to 'set' instead.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza Yes, if those values are only being set once, you could even toss them into a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is just a suggestion and by far not the only solution possible. It uses abstract classes by letting `Player` implement the `PlayerAttribute` interface:

```
 public interface PlayerAttributes {

  PlayerPosition getPlayerPosition(PlayerPosition position);

  Float getAttackPower(Float value);
  Float getDefensePower(Float value);
}

abstract class Player implements PlayerAttributes {

  String name;
  Integer number;

  @Override
  public PlayerPosition getPlayerPosition(PlayerPosition position) {
    return PlayerPosition.DEFENDER;
  }

  @Override
  public Float getAttackPower(Float value) {
    return value * attackPowerMultiplier();
  }

  public Float getDefensePower(Float value) {
    return value * defensePowerMultiplier();
  }

  public abstract Float attackPowerMultiplier();
  public abstract Float defensePowerMultiplier();
}

class Defender extends Player implements PlayerAttributes {
  public static final Float ATTACK_POWER_MUTLIPLIER = 1.2f;
  public static final Float DEFENSE_POWER_MUTLIPLIER = 2.5f;

  @Override public Float attackPowerMultiplier() {
    return ATTACK_POWER_MUTLIPLIER;
  }

  @Override public Float defensePowerMultiplier() {
    return DEFENSE_POWER_MUTLIPLIER;
  }
}

enum PlayerPosition {
  DEFENDER
}
```

The `get<Type>PowerMultiplier()`-methods will still be pretty similar, but this approach tries to minimize repetition.

---

Two remarks on your code:

- You go a little bit wild with floating-poinnt types. In general, if a method accepts a `float`, it should return a `float` (same for `double`) unless it is blatantly obvious that a conversion is necessary or intended.
- Is there a reason why you are using wrapper-objects instead of primitives? Especially with type conversion, this can lead to ugly situations.

Comment: You've got me on this, now that you've pointed out these points I think that my mind got a bit high trying to use Wrappers instead of primitives. There was no reason at all. I'll take some time and implement your suggestion to see how it will work.

Comment: I like the idea of getting rid of those magic numbers into the methods! Thanks!